# GLPI agent additional content

Tags: web, centos8, agent, glpi

I am looking to retrieve specific information within my context using the GLPI agent. My research has left me puzzled as to whether it is possible or not...

Some researchs suggest that it is possible, but I am struggling to apply it to my situation.

If I understand correctly, if it is feasible, I need to use a .json file, which will be called through the additional-content option.

So in my case, I would have a script that retrieves the information I need (specific to my environment, not already present in what is retrieved from the agent) and puts it in a .json file formatted as the agent expects.

How can I then link this with the fields I see in GLPI? And potentially, in the fields I have added via the Additional Fields plugin?

Context:
GLPI v10.0.6
GLPI-agent v1.7.1